# Load-time weaving with Spring, Eclipselink and Weblogic 10.x server

Tags: spring, weblogic, eclipselink, weblogic-10.x, load-time-weaving

Can someone provide really working, verified configuration of Spring load-time weaving using EclipseLink on Weblogic server?
It seems that docs ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-spring ) are simply not true.
I succeeded to make it work in Glasfish 3.x (not 2.x). However no luck with Weblogic.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Not true?   That's a strongly worded statement.  Is there no possibility that perhaps you made a mistake?  Zero?  None?

Comment: Maybe somewhat strong words, sorry. But it just "seems" so. Didn't found anyone who succeeded in this.  I also made it work for Glasfish 3.x, Tomcat 6/7